# Increased virtual disk size (vid) but /dev/mapper seems to be unchanged

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, virtualbox

I run a webserver on a virtual box, which needed to be increased in disk size;
so I expanded the vdi using vboxmanage command and repartitioned to full capacity.
Now fdisk -l says what follows:

```
Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048   499711   497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 61439999 60938242 29.1G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       501760 61439999 60938240 29.1G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/HRMANAGER--vg-root: 7.4 GiB, 7885291520 bytes, 15400960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/HRMANAGER--vg-swap_1: 392 MiB, 411041792 bytes, 802816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

As you can see the **Linux LVM is 30GB** as I needed (**it was 8GB**), but what I'm fearing is that it's still not recognizing the right partition size as the /dev/mapper/ sizes are still 8GB.
I need that extraspace as the server is going to be full in a few days.
Can you explain me please if I have to tweak some other configurations?
Thank you.

Comment: I want to mention that I easily resolved my problem using the following package: `system-config-lvm` through a live distro. Credits to _Cao Minh Tu_ http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use `pvresize` to increase the physical LVM volume to use the entire partition:

http://linux.die.net/man/8/pvresize

```
pvresize /dev/sda5
```

Then you need to allocate that extra physical space to the logical volume with `lvextend`.

Finally you need to expand the filesystem using some appropriate tool depending on what filesystem you are using.

In order to increase the amount of files you can store on a LVM-backed file system on a VM you need to:

1. Increase the size of the virtual disk (or add a new one)
2. Increase the size of the partition (or add a new one)
3. Increase the size the LVM physcial volume (or add a new one)

   1. If you added a new one, you need to add it to the volume group
4. Add the new LVM space to the logical volume you want to increase
5. Expand the filesystem to fill the extra space

You have done 1 and 2. Now you need to do 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: Sorry fdisk -l is saying that the LVM is already at maximum am I wrong?

Comment: No fdisk is saying the partition is at full size. There are many layers above that. You need to do 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: Ok. Is gparted suitable for that or am I requried to use lvextend?

Comment: `lvextend` is used for step 4. `pvresize` is used for step 3. Something specific to your filesystem is used for step 5.